# Where do I pay income tax and how?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, india, contractor

When I was in the US before, I worked for a company as a independent contractor under 1099. Now I've come back to India, and I am still working for that same company. The company deposits my pay in my US Bank account. Where do I pay income tax and how?

Comment: As this is a tax question it is best answered by a tax professional.

Comment: Since when you have been in India?